# Getting 'Access token has been revoked' while login in AWS Cognito from my Android Application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In my app I'm using AWS Cognito for User Login and Management. Earlier(almost a year) it was running good, but from past few days I'm getting an strange error message saying **'Access token has been revoked'** while login. Irony is, I have not changed any code in my app or any settings on AWS Console. Unable to figure out what is happening? Please help?

**Note: I'm getting this error message only sometimes not all the times.**

Comment: Have you been re-using the same refresh token for a long time? Does anyone else have access to your application?

Comment: I am getting this error while login in Cognito UserPool using username and password, so refresh token does not come in picture at the time of login. And my application is currently under development so the beta tester have access to this but my main concern is that everyone gets this error message sometimes while login or signup.

Comment: had the same problem and realized it was happening when i changed username. so i guess a refresh token is required in my case.

Comment: Facing the same issue. What do you do with the refresh token? You mean just needs to be returned? I face this after changing the password.

Comment: @AbhimanyuRaj Same issue. How did you resolve this?